# Automatically decide array element return type based on array value for each index

Tags: javascript, typescript

I want to create a function with array of literal string from available key.

If first index using SECOND_KEY, in that index it must return that SECOND_TYPE type, and so on.

The code is below, and I provide comments to elaborate more:

```
type TestType = {
  FIRST_KEY: number,
  SECOND_KEY: string
}

function TestFunction<keyType extends (keyof TestType)[]>(keys: keyType) {
  return await AsyncStorage.multiGet(keys)

  /*
    from multiGet, probably the data will be like this

    [
      2,
      "Test string",
      2
    ]
  */
}

let arr = TestFunction(['FIRST_KEY', 'SECOND_KEY', 'FIRST_KEY'])

// arr[0] should have type number, and be able to access number methods like .toPrecision
// arr[1] should have type string, and be able to access string methods like .length
// arr[2] should have type number, and be able to access number methods like .toPrecision
```

Comment: That's not possible.  Type checks are transpile time. Values are runtime.

Comment: having a hard time trying to figure out what you are trying to do, but if you have a function that has different return types based on the input, that is just bad coding. I would go in a different direction.

Comment: I don't think you can. You need to return a *tuple* type, not an array type, if you want different types by index. The closest you could get would be something like `(string | number)[]` https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwFBSgMQEkAlAZRgH0BpAUQE0AuKAOwFcBbAIwgCcAaHKCWoBhAPIA5ACJU6jRNwCWTAOZYAvliwAzFkwDGwBQHsmsBMDy6DxpgB4A1hBDJIUCAA9gEJgBN4UAApHECMtM0QXCABKAD4gp3hGYMiAbQBdKMYAuAiUFOSUDPTMAW4IYBZuU2KAehr8AgANAFlqKAA-KABDUy7ubi6QXigFMOCR-y0FbkRyceAAC28oRa7gEd8PKBZ4JWVmdi4+EbGnCah4CD0THzmzxeXV9aUfLbKKqu6L4EUVdU0ADblbr9KDoHIWKyGEwBFIAckIpAoNFocOGcKEYikMlR6MRZBxcIyAG4sEA

Comment: @ThomasSablik no I don't use runtime values, just using literal string from keyof then decide the return value based on that literal string

Comment: You're right.  That's probably possible.

Comment: @jonrsharpe yes it can be like that, string and number are just my example, but i have lots of types, I can't do (Type1 | Type2 | Type3 | Type4) and have all the type suggestion merge, it will be confusing

Comment: i have updated it, to give more idea about my use case, at multiGet function

Comment: @NaldPrabha it is doable.  I am writing you an answer right now :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Typescript will interpret your generic type parameter as a normal array `("FIRST_KEY" | "SECOND_KEY")[]` which can have any length and can have these values in any order.

We need to force Typescript to interpret it as a fixed  [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types).  We can do that by adding `as const` when we call the function, and by adding `readonly` to the generic in order to allow constant tuples which are `readonly`.

We need a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to convert our tuple of keys to a tuple of values.  Mapped types can be applied directly to tuples.

Within the body of the function, you will need to assert correctness with `as` because calling methods like `.map` on your function will cause it to be seen as normal array again.

Your actual use case regards `AsyncStorage`/`localStorage` where the value that you get will always be a `string`.  You will need to convert it to a `number` with `parseFloat` in certain cases.  This is a run-time action and cannot be done just with types.  Your code needs to know which variables it should convert.  Here we only have two keys, so we can deal with it on an `if`/`then` basis, but you might need to rethink how you handle casting in your actual app.

```
type TestType = {
    FIRST_KEY: number,
    SECOND_KEY: string
}

type TestValue<T> = {
    [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends keyof TestType ? TestType[T[K]] : never;
}

function TestFunction<keyType extends readonly (keyof TestType)[]>(keys: keyType): TestValue<keyType> {
    return keys.map(key => {
        const raw = localStorage.getItem(key); // is either string or null
        if (key === "FIRST_KEY") {
            return parseFloat(raw ?? "");
        } else {
            return raw ?? "";
        }
    }) as unknown as TestValue<keyType>;
}

let arr = TestFunction(['FIRST_KEY', 'SECOND_KEY', 'FIRST_KEY'] as const)
const [a, b, c] = arr; // types a: number, b: string, c: number
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/Nr2n1N)

Comment: yap, i know i will have to parse it from string when to use multiget hahah, this is awesome, it's like what I expected!!! thanks for the answer

Comment: I was thinking before that you would probably have different parsing methods for different types of data, like `parseFloat`, but now I've realized that you can probably just use `JSON.Stringify` and `JSON.parse` for everything!  You would have to assert the type when using `JSON.parse` but we are already doing that.  So I guess the only remaining issue is what to do when it's not found.  You could always `throw` an `Error`.  Or you could have some map of default values somewhere.